# Python / Hash SHA256 - El resultado del hash para archivos es siempre único?

Tags: python, hash, sha256

Por ejemplo, tengo una carpeta que contiene otras carpetas, estas últimas contienen archivos .pdf y .xml (Por ahora no son .pdf válidos, son solo pdf porque añadí la extensión, al igual que los .xml aunque ambos tienen un contenido.):

```
> EMR
    > carpeta1
        > some.pdf
        > some.xml
```

El resto son copias de carpeta1, entonces **al iterar dentro de EMR en búsqueda de los xml y pdf, y por medio de su ruta calcular el SHA256, el resultado siempre será único?**

Esta es mi función para calcular el SHA256:

```
import hashlib
def SHA256_Checksum(ruta):
    h = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(ruta, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
        for b in iter(lambda : f.read(128*1024), b''):
            h.update(b)
    return h.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por definición un HASH es determinista, es decir, a una misma entrada le corresponde la misma salida. Mientras la lógica con la que leas los "bytes" de los archivos sea siempre la misma, el hash que obtengas para un mismo archivo va a ser siempre el mismo.

El otro problema intrínseco de todo algoritmo de hash son las "colisiones", en tu ejemplo sería el caso absolutamente improbable que encuentres dos archivos distintos que tienen el mismo hash. En algoritmos más antiguos se ha logrado calcular y generar estas colisiones, por eso, casos como MD5, SHA-0, SHA-1, fueron siendo descartadas de los usos criptográficos.